# Proving properties of vector fields

Tags: calculus, functions

I must prove the given properties for the vector fields $F$ and $G$, and scalar functions $f$ and $g$.
Assume that all required partial derivatives exist and are continuous.
$$
\operatorname{div}(f F) = f \operatorname{div} F + (\nabla f · F)
$$
I completed the problem before this by setting $F$ to $Ai + Bj + Ck$ and $G$ to $Di + Ej + Fk$, and used these to prove that $\operatorname{curl}(F+G) = \operatorname{curl} F + \operatorname{curl} G$. That worked out fine, as I just plugged the values into the formula and demonstrated that after refactoring the results, they are the same.

For this problem however, I'm really not sure where to start. Maybe by splitting it up into parts? I can't find much on this in my notes and I'm pretty confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Write del as three partial differention operators (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates)( use cartesian). And then use multiplication rule for the left hand side, for each operator.

Comment: Write $fF = (fA)i + (fB)j + (fC)k$ and apply the definition of div. Then the gradient of $f$ will appear as you do the calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot(f\vec F)&=\sum_i\hat x_i\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}\cdot(f\sum_j \hat x_jF_j)\\\\
&=\sum_i\sum_j(\hat x_i \cdot \hat x_j)\frac{\partial(fF_j) }{\partial x_i}\tag 1\\\\
&=\sum_i\frac{\partial(fF_i) }{\partial x_i}\tag 2\\\\
&=\sum_i\left(f\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_i}+F_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right)\tag 3\\\\
&\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{=f\nabla \cdot \vec F+\vec F\cdot \nabla f}
\end{align}$$

as expected.

---

NOTES:

In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we used the fact the $\hat x_i\cdot \hat x_j=\delta_{ij}$, where $\delta_{ij}=0$ for $i\ne j$ and $\delta_{ij}=1$ for $i=j$.

In going from $(2)$ to $(3)$, we used the product rule for differentiation.

Comment: Not much more to say after that!  ***Endorsed!!!***

Comment: @RobertLewis Wow!  Thanks!! Very much appreciative.

Comment: My pleasure, Doc!  Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  This approach works well in general for proving vector identities.